# separate values from a string using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this requirement where we need to separate values from a string the format of the  is like

```
{Feature1=Value1} | {Feature2=Value2} | .. | {FeatureN=ValueN}

{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}
```

so need to separate features and values from the given srting..

To separate PIPE separated values i am using..

```
select * 
  from xmltable('r/c' passing xmltype('<r><c>' || replace('{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}','|','</c><c>') || '</c></r>')
columns new_str varchar2(30) path '.');

NEW_STR                    
------------------------------
{12345=Gold}                 
{12346=Silver}
```

I am writing a PLSQL block which iterate through each pipe separate values using above query.
I can store these values in PLSQL variable.

Now another task here  is to get features and values from two above strings for this i write below SQL

```
select substr ('{12345=Gold}',2, instr('{12345=Gold}', '=')-2) features from dual;

FEATURES
----------------------
12345

SELECT SUBSTR('{12345=Gold}', instr('{12345=Gold}', '=')+1, LENGTH(substr ('{12345=Gold}', instr('{12345=Gold}', '=')+1, INSTR('{12345=Gold}', '}', 2)))-1) value FROM DUAL;

VALUE
--------------
Gold
```

So here i am able to get the features and values from a string......

I am looking for another or alternate SQL for my SQL's specially for the last one i find it complex function use so if you have any better idea for the above scenario then please  Post !

Please ask if the scenario is not clear

MY DB is --

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2):

```
with line as (
      select '{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}|{12399=Copper}' str from dual)

select substr (parse, 2, instr(parse,'=')-2) as feature
      ,substr (parse, instr(parse,'=')+1, length(parse)-instr(parse,'=')-1 ) as value
from
   (select distinct regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, level) as parse
    from line
    connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using types and a handy built-in package called apex_util:

```
create type keyval_t is object (key varchar2(10), value varchar2(100));
/

create type keyval_tab_t is table of keyval_t;
/

create or replace package test_pkg is
   function keyval_tab (p_keyval_string varchar2) return keyval_tab_t;
end;
/

create or replace package body test_pkg is
   function keyval_tab (p_keyval_string varchar2) return keyval_tab_t
   is
      l_tab apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
      l_tab2 apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
      l_keyval_tab keyval_tab_t := keyval_tab_t();
      l_str long;
   begin
      -- Split string at pipe delimiters
      l_tab := apex_util.string_to_table (p_keyval_string, '|');
      -- For each {key=value} pair
      for i in 1..l_tab.count loop
         l_str := l_tab(i);

         -- Remove the {}
         l_str := ltrim (l_str, '{ ');
         l_str := rtrim (l_str, '} ');

         -- Split string into key and value
         l_tab2 := apex_util.string_to_table (l_str, '=');
         if l_tab2.count = 2 then
            l_keyval_tab.extend;
            l_keyval_tab(i) := keyval_t (l_tab2(1), l_tab2(2));
         else
            -- ?? invalid string
            null;
         end if;
      end loop;
      return l_keyval_tab;
   end;

end;
/
```

Now you can query:

```
SQL> select value from table(test_pkg.keyval_tab ('{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}'))
  2* where key='12346';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Silver

SQL> select key from table(test_pkg.keyval_tab ('{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}'))
  2  where value='Gold';

KEY
----------
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to get your expected output. Sorry if there are too many replace functions. But this is quite easier.

```
select EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/row/Code') code,
        EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/row/Value') Value
from TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<rowset><row>'||replace(replace(replace(replace('{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}','}|{','</Value></row><row><Code>'),'{','<Code>'),'=','</Code><Value>'),'}','</Value>')||'</row></rowset>'),'/rowset/row')));
```

Comment: your query is not running here it says XML PARSING FAILED !

Comment: Please check the query again, because I even tried in Oracle 12c. Results are as expected

Comment: Very well its working now :). So what would you suggest should i use mine or which one is better !

Comment: May I have your query please

Comment: I suggest you to use my query since it doesn't involve a PL/SQL block or extra query to separate the values.

Comment: yeah you are write however i need to write it in PLSQL :) as it is for a big migration i need your help again can you tell me why this error i am getting as i am using same query as you have given me but for a different string

Comment: select EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/row/Code') code,
       EXTRACTVALUE (COLUMN_VALUE, '/row/Value') Value
from TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(XMLTYPE('<rowset><row><code>'||replace(replace('12345_Gold|12346_Silver','|','</Value></row><row><Code>'),'_','</Code><Value>')||'</Value>'||'</row></rowset>'),'/rowset/row')));

Comment: <rowset><row><code>12345</Code><Value>Gold</Value></row><row><Code>12346</Code><Value>Silver</Value></row></rowset> This is XML generating with above query and it is same as yours but it is giving me error ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
LPX-00225: end-element tag "Code" does not match start-element tag "code"

Comment: Hey i got the error it is because of C of Code and c of code :) in the tag creation anyways thanks for your query it helps me make my code easy to maintain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have separated columns into rows the work to do is fairly simple with `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

Considering that your cols now is:

```
NEW_STR                    
--------------
{12345=Gold}                 
{12346=Silver}
```

You can do this sql to transform it into two different columns:

```
select regexp_replace( col, '\{(\d+)=\w+\}', '\1' ) as feature,
       regexp_replace( col, '\{\d+=(\w+)\}', '\1' ) as value
  from testTable
```

Transform that into a view and then just select with columns as you like:

```
create or replace view testView as
   select regexp_replace( col, '\{(\d+)=\w+\}', '\1' ) as feature,
          regexp_replace( col, '\{\d+=(\w+)\}', '\1' ) as value
     from testTable
```

Then just do:

```
select * from testView where feature = '12345'
```

Or

```
Select * from testView where value = 'Gold'
```

If you like to transform the feature value as a number just use the `to_number` function on that column as:

```
to_number(regexp_replace( col, '\{(\d+)=\w+\}', '\1' ))
```

Remember that in order to do this you must be absolute sure that it is only numbers on that, otherwise you will have conversion errors

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a pivot table and REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
with MyStrings as
 (select '{Feature1=Value1}|{Feature2=Value2}|{FeatureN=ValueN}' Str from dual
  union all
  select '{12345=Gold}|{12346=Silver}' from dual
  )
,pivot as (
  Select Rownum Pnum
  From dual
  Connect By Rownum <= 100   
  )
SELECT rownum rn
      ,REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'[^|]+',1,pv.pnum) TXT
  FROM MyStrings ms
      ,pivot pv
where REGEXP_SUBSTR (ms.Str,'[^|]+',1,pv.pnum) is not null
```